# Matlab: custom distribution of random numbers

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I have a set of random numbers

```
randi([1 100],1,50) % numbers from 1 to 100 in a 1x50 array.
```

I want them to have a 1/x^2 distribution. I couldn't find a direct command to do that. I read about pdf functions but I'm not that familiar with matlab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the following page from MathWorks help? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generating-random-data.html

Comment: does it suppose to be discrete or continuous ?

Comment: This is rather a mathematical question. Check out those approaches [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/how-to-generate-numbers-based-on-an-arbitrary-discrete-distribution) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-number-generator-in-arbitrary-probability-distribution-fashion/). The idea is to fit a uniform random distribution (e.g. by `rng`) to the structure of a certain distribution. You can also have a look at the [Ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) algorithms, which explains how to get a normal distribution from a uniform random generator

Comment: If you want a discrete distribution, you can use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) with the optional fourth input, which lets you specify an arbitrary discrete distribution

Comment: Is the probability mass function = 1 / (x^2) = x^(-2) for integers 1 to 100?  Wanting to clarify before working up an answer.